# Can I manually edit flyway schema_version data?

Tags: db2, schema, flyway

I am just start to supporting a project that is using flyway to manage the db script.

I have create a db script with version V14.9.10.8_insertTemplate.sql.

In this sql, I have a insert script, to insert a row of data into db.

After this, I run flyway migrate command, and the data successful insert into db.

However, I found that the data that I insert is wrong, I wish to change it.

As my understanding, Flyway will not run back this script because it already run and it store in `schema_version` table.

Can I edit the `schema_version` table by delete this version so that I can rerun this script? If yes, May I know how can I do it, I am using dbvisualizer to run the `select * from schema_version` but I hitting  `"DB2INST1.SCHEMA_VERSION" is an undefined name`.

Or should I create another script with later version like V14.9.10.9_updateTemplate.sql to change my data? I am just thinking is it better to no have this extra update script, since the wrong data inserted is cause by my own mistake.

I am using db2.

Answer (score 0):

the flyway history table is named "flyway_schema_history" by default, is it created in lower case.
If it's a dev environment you can go ahead and delete the migration from the history table.
If you use the teams edition of flyway it offers an undo command, you can read about this here:

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/tutorials/undo.html

if the data is already in production I recommend to provide a new script to correct the first one, versions are incremental and you cannot alter a script after it has been applied to the database.